# Is Windows 10 Mobile The Same As Windows 10 IoT for Mobile

Tags: insider-preview, windows-10-mobile

I've found conflicting documentation between the new Windows phones being called Windows 10 Mobile, or Windows 10 IoT for Mobile depending on what site or technical evangelist I'm reading.

I'm looking to upgrade a Windows 8.1 Handheld Embedded to Windows 10 IoT for Mobile, however I'm not sure whether it falls under 10 Mobile, or 10 IoT for mobile since the core of the Windows 8.1 Handheld Embedded is technically Windows Phone 8.1 in it's core.

Does anyone know if these two OS's are one in the same, and if they're not which version did they announce that 8.1 Embedded Handheld will go to on the upgrade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In answer to the original question, no. Windows 10 Mobile and Windows 10 IoT are not the same thing. W10M is what goes on phones. Windows 10 IoT is the OS you can use on things like a Raspberry Pi.

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt412023(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows 8.1 Embedded will be upgraded to Windows 10 Mobile.

Comment: Is there a IoT Mobile though?  The documentation on IoT (not just IoT core) seems to suggest this  https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/03/18/windows-10-iot-powering-the-internet-of-things/

Comment: If there is, I've not seen any signs of it. And there's no mention of multiple versions made here: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/05/13/introducing-windows-10-editions/ . Perhaps someone else knows otherwise, though?

Comment: Hopefully some time in the future Microsoft themselves will clarify it.  Until then I'll keep searching.  Thanks!

Comment: IoT Mobile is just a new name for Embedded Handheld. I.e. normal windows mobile 10 OS with lock down features.

Answer (score 0):

After the deployment of Windows 10 Phone Enterprise edition (released on 12/01/2015 on MSDN) they've declared this to be the platform that 8.1 Embedded Handhelds will go to.